# Kal Calender Disappears when clicked Tab

Tags: ios, uitabbar, kal

When I click the tab bar that holds my kal calendar the calendar disappears:

[image]

This is my code in viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:YES];
    calendar.dataSource = self;
    calendar.delegate = self;
    [calendar reloadData];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
}
```

I also have this method:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
     [self viewWillAppear:YES];
     //Even when I comment out this line the problem stays!
}
```

If you need more infomation just ask.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your tab bar controller improperly. Indeed, you should populate it with your controllers (either in Interface Builder or by setting the tab bar controller's `controllers` property) and let it do its job.

On another coin, note that `viewWillAppear` can be called multiple times, so this is the last place where you want to allocate a new controller.
If you have overridden `viewWillAppear` in order for your controller to show something when it s view is displayed that is not the correct approach.

EDIT:

If you create your UI programmatically, these are the steps you should follow in you `application:didFinishLaunching:` to setup the rootViewController:

```
FirstViewController *fistVC = ...
SecondViewController *secondVC = ...
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = ...

NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:fistVC, secondVC, thirdVC, nil];

self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
```

If you build your UI in Interface Builder, you will do the same graphically, but I cannot reproduce it here.

In any case, I hope this snippet clarifies the way the tab bar controller works: you instantiate all of its controllers, put them in an array, pass the array to the tab bar controller. No need to instantiate anymore the tabbed controllers (neither in viewWillAppear nor in viewDidLoad)...

Comment: So I should do this in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: When the view appears I want the Kal to be on the screen.

Comment: I understand what you are saying however when I try this my program crashes... I am using Kal: https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Comment: then everything is working correctly, I think -- the tabs are there and in your screenshot the calendar is displayed correctly. so what happens that makes you "force" calendar creation in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @serigo I really do not know why this is happening... I moved the code in viewDidLoad and I put breakpoint yet no code is happing when I click the Tabbars

Comment: I do not mean "why" -- I asked "what" is happening... :-) I cannot see your app running and I have not clear what happens when you launch it: do you see the tabs? what is the content of the tab bar controller? what are you expecting? this kind of stuff so that I understand what is happening... :-)

Comment: Ohhh sorry Basically I have a tab-bar controller with 5 view controllers in it. In the first tab I have a navigation controller which is embedded in a view controller. In the viewdidload I call `KalViewController *calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:YES];`

Comment: possibly, then, your navigation controller's `viewDidLoad` is not called because it is embedded in your other view controller. how do you embed it? could try and put the navigation controller itself in your fist tab? then your code above in `viewDidLoad`...

Comment: in your last picture, check that the view controller on the right has the `KalViewController` type -- so, it will be instantiate automatically. of course, remove your manual instantiation/push...

Comment: When I do that the program crashes

Comment: what crash message/log?

Comment: I fixed th bug: I had to add `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{return [self init];}` in my `KalViewController`